# Multiprocessing from an if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I have a quick question about threading and/or multiprocessing. Is there any simple way of killing a thread, and is it possible to start a process from an if statement.

I am very new to coding and don't know big terms in coding so some other answers are hard for me to understand.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
done = False

def a():
    print('a')

p = Process(target = a)

while not done:
    userInput = input('')
    if userInput == '1':
        p.start()
    if userInput == '2':
        done = True
```

```
import threading
done = False

def a():
    print('a')

p = threading.Thread(target = a)

while not done:
    userInput = input('')
    if userInput == '1':
        p.start()
    if userInput == '2':
        done = True
```

I was hoping that when I input 1 that it would have an output of a but it didn't do anything. When I tried again it gave me the error, AssertionError: cannot start a process twice. Is there anything I can do to fix this. I know threading works once but what would I have to add if I want to run a second time.

Comment: Both sample codes output ``a`` for me when I input ``1``. Do you input some trailing space before hitting enter, perhaps?

Comment: I might have I’ll check as soon as possible, I might have made that mistake.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi So I re-ran both codes and only the threading one worked again for me. The multiprocessing script did not work.